# JavaFX cannot find symbol symbol: class PixelBuffer on compile

Tags: java, javafx, vlc, vlcj

I installed the project demo from here https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx-demo and followed this tutorial exactly to install and run it in the latest version of IntelliJ on Mac: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzmokfajN0o

But unlike in the video I get this error when launching the program:

```
Error:(39, 26) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PixelBuffer
  location: package javafx.scene.image
```

The only difference seems to be I'm using Mac and in the video a pc is used. It clearly works as is since we see it running in the video linked above so the code cannot have any actual errors. There are no errors showing anywhere in the project for me either. If I search for 'PixelBuffer' using navigate class in IntelliJ it also finds it no problem:

[image]

I've spoken with the developer at length about it and he was as clueless as I am to why it would not work so if anyone can shed some light on this it would be great.

Comment: First of all, it'd better if you'd post the problematic code itself. Secondly, I'm not a Mac user, but if I'm not mistaken, Mac OS different delimiters.. maybe the code doesn't consider that part..? I can't find respective package in the project you've linked.

Comment: @Giorgi Tsiklauri The code is linked, it's in my first sentence. It would clutter up the whole question if I posted it all here so it's better to just open the page and view it. It uses Maven in pom.xml to get the dependencies. If you watch the video you can see how it works from start to finish in under a minute.

Comment: It looks like you are running the program with an older version of JavaFX than the one you used to compile the program. Print out the version string of JavaFX at runtime to verify that. Something like log.debug("javafx.runtime.version: {}", System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version", "(undefined)"));

Comment: @mipa Can't run anything like that since it crashes on the line 39 import before anything happens. How could it not be running the right version of JavaFX if the dependencies are controlled in Maven anyway?

Comment: @mipa Managed to get it to print out the JavaFX version by commenting out all the Pixelbuffer references. It says "javafx.runtime.version: 14+9" which is exactly right so there should be no problem....

Comment: Maybe my example code here https://github.com/mipastgt/JFXToolsAndDemos#vlcjfxvideoplayer is easier to build and run.

Comment: probably relevant https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/883 you should share your exact code used (there is a bunch of project in the repo linked), add that info to your original Q, and share *full* logs

Comment: @mfkl There's only one project that I'm aware of in that link. If you follow the video tutorial I posted in my question, you just clone the git URL from that page.

Comment: @mipa Thanks for your code link but I really thought the official demo should run. He has it set up and running in under a minute in the video. Really don't see how it's failing to find pixel buffer.